# trying to import a module: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8

Tags: python, linux, glib

import glib fails with:

`ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glib/_glib.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8`

How can I fix this?

Python version is Python 2.7.3rc2. The OS is Debian.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The module was built against a Python that was built with UCS-4 as its internal `unicode` representation. Your Python was built with UCS-2 as its internal representation. Rebuild the module, or rebuild Python.

This issue is mentioned in [the official FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2.7/faq/extending.html#when-importing-module-x-why-do-i-get-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2).  This is discussed in-depth [in python issue 8654](http://bugs.python.org/issue8654).

Comment: If possible I would prefer to have my package manager replace it instead of building it myself but I suppose that's another question.

Comment: I highly suspect that the package manager wasn't involved with installing that version of Python in the first place.

Comment: This is also mentioned in [the official FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2.7/faq/extending.html#when-importing-module-x-why-do-i-get-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2).  This is discussed in-depth [in this python issue 8654](http://bugs.python.org/issue8654).

Comment: How I build Python with UCS-4?