# import healpy unicode error with enthought canopy python

Tags: python, ubuntu, unicode, enthought, healpy

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10

Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 64 bit

I have succesfully installed healpy using the direct Healpix configuration as well as using sud pip install healpy, and have made sure PYTHONPATH was set accordingly in the bashrc.

When I try to import healpy I get this unicode incomparability related error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/healpy/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from sphtfunc import (anafast, map2alm,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/healpy/sphtfunc.py", line 26, in <module>
    import _sphtools as _sphtools
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/healpy/_sphtools.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8
```

Related issues have solutions that require rebuilding.  I'm not sure how to go about doing this, and was wondering if there is an easier solution.  Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871799/trying-to-import-a-module-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs4-decodeutf8

Comment: Exactly what do you mean PYTHONPATH set "accordingly"? (See warnings in https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-). Why are you using sudo pip? If you are installing into Enthought Canopy Python, by default you are installing into home dir.

Comment: (It looks as if you are entangling your system python and Canopy Python.)