# How Do I Ensure That All Modules Are Imported From Same Location Within Virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am running python based software that requires a virtualenv with various additional python packages installed therein. Here are the install instructions:

```
Clone the repository to a shared filesysem on a cluster

    >git clone https://github.com/jgurtowski/nanocorr
    >cd nanocorr        

    Create a virtual environment to install python dependencies

    >virtualenv nanocorr_ve
    >source nanocorr_ve/bin/activate

    install the following packages using pip:

        pip install git+https://github.com/cython/cython
        pip install numpy
        pip install h5py
        pip install git+https://github.com/jgurtowski/pbcore_python
        pip install git+https://github.com/jgurtowski/pbdagcon_python
        pip install git+https://github.com/jgurtowski/jbio
        pip install git+https://github.com/jgurtowski/jptools

    #Finally install the nanocorr package itself

    > python setup.py install
```

I achieved this with no problems. However, While running the software, I found that it was failing with the following traceback.

```
(nanocorr_ve)[nanocorr_test]$ correctOxford
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File    "/local/workdir/malonge/nanocorr_test/nanocorr/nanocorr_ve/bin/correctOxford",     line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('jptools==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'correctOxford')()
  File     "/local/workdir/malonge/nanocorr_test/nanocorr/nanocorr_ve/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File     "/local/workdir/malonge/nanocorr_test/nanocorr/nanocorr_ve/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File     "/local/workdir/malonge/nanocorr_test/nanocorr/nanocorr_ve/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File     "/local/workdir/malonge/nanocorr_test/nanocorr/nanocorr_ve/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File     "/local/workdir/malonge/nanocorr_test/nanocorr/nanocorr_ve/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/jptools/correct.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pbtools.pbdagcon.q_sense import output_dag_info
  File     "/local/workdir/malonge/nanocorr_test/nanocorr/nanocorr_ve/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pbtools/pbdagcon/q_sense.py", line 50, in <module>
    from pbcore.io import FastaReader
  File "/programs/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbcore-1.0.0-    py2.7.egg/pbcore/io/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .BasH5IO import *
  File "/programs/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbcore-1.0.0-    py2.7.egg/pbcore/io/BasH5IO.py", line 37, in <module>
    import h5py, numpy as np, os.path as op
  File "/programs/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py-2.5.0-py2.7-linux-    x86_64.egg/h5py/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _errors
 ImportError: /programs/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py-2.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/h5py/_errors.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8
```

I have found details as to the [specific error itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871799/trying-to-import-a-module-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs4-decodeutf8), but I think the source of the problem is that the traceback clearly shows a transition from modules being imported from the /local virtualenv site-packages to another site-packages directory in /programs.

My question is the following: Given that I have the same python packages installed in two separate places, 1 in the system wide location and one in virtualenv, how do I ensure that other programs properly import all modules from within the same virtualenv sit-packages directory. I thought this would have been done automatically. I am not 100% sure that this is the sole reason for the error, but being able to fix this would help me to further debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you set up your env.  `virtualenv` has a flag option that forces it to not use the system site packages

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages my_env
```

It is the default behavior for recent versions (>=1.7).

If you've defined a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, that will affect your `virtualenv` environment as well.

Comment: I have defined a PYTHONPATH variable which specifies /programs/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Comment: Removing the PYTHONPATH variable should fix your problem.  The default python should already be looking in the site-packages directory, even without it being defined in the PYTHONPATH

Comment: Great I will give this a try. Thank you.

Comment: It turned out to be the PYTHONPATH variable, as I am running a version of virtualenv >=1.7. Thanks again.