# virtualenv with python interpreter newer than systemwide interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, virtualenv, pygtk

**EDIT: If you vote this question to be a duplicate, please do at least take the time to read the question instead of just flagging it a duplicate because it looks somewhat similar to another question. If you would have done that, you would immediately realize that it is not a duplicate. I'm merely trying to show some wider context.**

My distro still uses Python 2.6 as python interpreter. Now I want to use a module, which needs Python 2.7. I installed Python 2.7, but it would break other applications. So I set up a virtual environment with Python 2.7 as interpreter:

```
virtualenv -p ~/pkg/bin/python2.7 venv
```

If I activate the virtual environment and run python the new interpreter is used. Good! Now I need to `import` modules, e.g.

```
import gtk
```

This works globally (i.e. in Python 2.6), but not in my virtual environment (i.e. in Python 2.7). I tried to set the `sys.path` the same for the virtual environment, but this would give me errors such as

> ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/glib/_glib.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8

which is somewhat expected.

A search with

```
pip search gtk
```

would not lead any results either. My best guess right now is that I have to install gtk from source, and compile it against Python 2.7. However, this pulls in other dependencies and going down that hole for about 7 or 8 steps, I resigned.

Is there an easier way to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to import a module: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4\_DecodeUTF8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871799/trying-to-import-a-module-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs4-decodeutf8)

Comment: @snakecharmerb not that. And pfnuesel: No, you cannot use Python 2.6 C extensions in Python 2.7 whatsoever. Instead: consider upgrading your operating system so that you get 2.7 *or* even better a decent Python 3.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, that makes sense to me. Upgrading, while good advice, is not possible unfortunately, since this is our server operating system which runs on several thousand servers.

Comment: @snakecharmerb See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

After you first activate your virtual environment, you need to install any packages you require (for example, `pip install pep8-naming`)

When you create a virtual environment, it basically acts as a separate standalone installation of python. If you previously installed `gtk` (or any other package) in the global Python 2.6 instance, that is not available within your Python 2.7 virtual environment.

Instead, you need to re-install any needed packages after switching to the environment.

For example, on my Mac, the default system python is 2.7

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

But I have many pythons installed:

```
$ python <tab><tab>
python             python2.7-32       python3.2m-config  python3.4m         pythonw2.7-32
python-32          python2.7-config   python3.3          python3.4m-config  pythonw3
python-config      python3            python3.3-32       pythontex          pythonw3-32
python2            python3-32         python3.3-config   pythonw            pythonw3.2
python2-32         python3-config     python3.3m         pythonw-32         pythonw3.2-32
python2-config     python3.2          python3.3m-config  pythonw2           pythonw3.3
python2.6          python3.2-32       python3.4          pythonw2-32        pythonw3.3-32
python2.6-config   python3.2-config   python3.4-32       pythonw2.6         
python2.7          python3.2m         python3.4-config   pythonw2.7
```

If I create a new virtualenv, you can see it has only the minimum packages  installed

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p `which python3.4` test
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4'
New python executable in test/bin/python3.4
Also creating executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...pdone.
$ pip list
pip (7.1.2)
setuptools (18.2)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

Comment: I understand all of that. My question is how to install `gtk` for an interpreter which is newer than the one installed on the system.

Comment: @pfnuesel, you use pip from/in the activated virtualenv.

Comment: So, you just wanted to know which package to install? Did you try `pip install PyGTK`?

Comment: @kdopen Yes. `pip install PyGTK` gives me `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyGTK (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyGTK`.